# MVC/ENTITY How to have user tables recreated after model change?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

I am using MVC4 beta and entity framework. I am using code first design and when I make changes to the model class files, i have it set to drop database and recreate but my problem is that the default user tables do not get recreated. How do I get those tables to get recreated each time?

Bonus question:  is there a way to keep the data in tables that have not been changed?

Comment: Sounds like you better use EF migrations in stead of drop & recreate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some research, the new version of EF seems to support this.

Comment: Can you please provide more detail? I can't see anything in MVC4/EF so far that helps you do it.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to make use of Database Initializers and their [Seed Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg679410%28v=vs.103%29)

[Database Initializers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/gg194002)

[Creating a Code First Database Initializer Strategy](http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/gilf/archive/2011/05/30/creating-a-code-first-database-initializer-strategy.aspx)